# Select div content before and after a given element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following HTML code :

```
<div id="content"> 
Lorem ipsum <b>dolor sit</b> amet... 
<myTag>Blablabla</myTag>
consectetur <b>adipiscing</b> elit...
</div>
```

What I want to do is to seperately extract

```
Lorem ipsum <b>dolor sit</b> amet...
```

And

```
consectetur <b>adipiscing</b> elit...
```

In other words, I would like to extract everything that is contained in the div before the element `<myTag>` and everything that is contained in the div after the element `<myTag>`

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: That's nice. good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: @MarcB Thought it was obvious, I edited my question with the "real" question. Thanks for the comment ;)

Comment: What @MarcB is getting at is...perhaps you should post what you've tried. You'll get more action that way.

Comment: you probably want to restructure your html to make this simpler.

Comment: In that case, it's just a DOM operation. Find the `mytag` node, then use previousSibling/nextSibling to get the neighboring content, basically.

Comment: I tried this (ok I should have stated it in the question I think), but previousSibling/nextSibling gives only the content of <b> tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var contentStr = $('#content').html();
var splitPos = '<myTag>' + $('myTag').html() + '</myTag>';
contentStr.split(splitPos);
```

You now have an array containing before and after.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works fine for my problem and seemed better than the others !

Answer (score 2):

before:

```
$('#content').html().split(/<mytag>.*<\/mytag>/)[0]
```

after:

```
$('#content').html().split(/<mytag>.*<\/mytag>/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get string from your div html and the use `substr()` like

```
var myString = $('#content').html();
var firstPart =  myString.substr(0,myString.indexOf('<myTag>'));
var secondPart = myString.substr(myString.lastIndexOf('</myTag>')+8);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdLwv0jf/)

Answer (score 0):

Get the text from parent element and cut myTag text from it

```
var a = $("myTag").parent().text();
a = a.replace($("myTag").text(), "");
```

Is that what you want?

Edit: Oh you want them separately, Y.Puzyrenko has posted an answer of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var content = $("#content").find('myTag').remove().end().html();
```

This gets the element by ID, finds "myTag", removes it, and then returns the HTML.

Comment: This is everything without the <myTag> content.  If you need separately see other answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  var content = $.map(
    $("#content").contents()
  , function(val, idx) {
      return $(val).is("myTag") ? null : val.outerHTML || val.textContent
  })
```

```js
var content = $.map(
    $("#content").contents()
  , function(val, idx) {
      return $(val).is("myTag") ? null : val.outerHTML || val.textContent
  })
console.log(content)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"> 
Lorem ipsum <b>dolor sit</b> amet... 
<myTag>Blablabla</myTag>
consectetur <b>adipiscing</b> elit...
</div>
```